# How to fetch the list of errors for invalid objects in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

Explanation: I have more than 200 invalid objects in my DB, the reasons could be couple of objects only (others due to dependancy). Is there a way we can select the object name and the 'Error Reason' for it being invalid.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could query **[DBA/ALL/USER]_ERRORS**. It describes current errors on all stored objects (views, procedures, functions, packages, and package bodies) owned by the current user.

Chose which view to query, depending on the privileges you have:

> - **DBA_**       : All objects in the database
> - **ALL_**       : All objects owned by the user and on which the user has been    granted privileges
> - **USER_**   : All objects owned by the user

For example,

I create a **procedure** with a **compilation error**, and I want to query the **error details**:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p
  2  BEGIN
  3  NULL
  4  END;
  5  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT NAME, TYPE, line, text FROM user_errors;

NAME  TYPE             LINE TEXT
----- ---------- ---------- --------------------------------------------------
P     PROCEDURE           2 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when exp
                            ecting one of the following:

                               ( ; is with authid as cluster compress order us
                            ing compiled
                               wrapped external deterministic parallel_enable
                            pipelined
                               result_cache accessible


SQL>
```

Read more about it in documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4315.htm)

Comment: It's just displaying the views that are invalid, not  the SPs, Packages, functions other objects. I saw the documentation and according to that all types should be displayed. I have read-only access, could that be a reason? Since the documentation states that ::"ALL_ERRORS describes current errors on all stored objects (views, procedures, functions, packages, and package bodies) accessible to the current user."

Comment: There are 3 views for the *_errors. Each can be accessed based on the privilege. Perhaps, you are only able to view current user's objects only. Can you check if the output is same with user_errors too. That would confirm you are viewing only current user objects. Please mark it as answered if it has helped you.

Comment: Thanks Lalit, I got the details from DBA_ERRORS.

Answer (score 6):

You can check with this view:

```
SELECT OWNER, OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE, STATUS
FROM ALL_OBJECTS
WHERE STATUS <> 'VALID';
```

resp. `USER_OBJECTS` or `DBA_OBJECTS`.

`ALL_ERRORS` does not show all invalid objects.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE tt (a NUMBER);
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ttt AS SELECT * FROM tt;
DROP TABLE tt;

SELECT * FROM USER_ERRORS;

no rows selected.
```

However, after selecting the view once you get an entry:

```
SELECT * FROM ttt;

Error at line 1
ORA-04063: view "xxxx.TTT" has errors

SELECT NAME, TYPE, TEXT FROM USER_ERRORS;

NAME    TYPE    TEXT
--------------------------------------------------------
TTT     VIEW    ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```