In Oracle, how to anticipate the error ORA 4061 existing state of has been invalidated?
We are running Oracle 19 database.
Sometimes when you have an urgent problem to solve we make changes directly on the production database. I know it's not recommended at all but let's imagine a case when we have no other choice.
We compile all the objects. No object is invalid, but yet we still get this error : existing state of package body "PACKAGE.NAME" has been invalidated persists
Sometimes the database may run smoothly until a process gets into a specific package then the entire database is unusable.
According to our analysis, checking for invalid objects is definitely not a way to anticipate this error.
Assuming a certain state of database objects, how can we detect that this error may happen? or be sure the change we have made to the database won't cause this error and everything is fine.
I have read the answer about how to reset the package state. But before moving to solving the problem I'm after a way to know that this error may occur. I want to do nothing on a production database that's not strictly required.
Edit
Here is a specific example :

A table has changed : A column added for example
Several objects will be invalidated
DBMS_UTILITY.compile_schema(schema => CurrentSchema, compile_all => true);    -- With this no object is in an invalid state
SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE STATUS <> 'VALID'; returns nothing
Now will the problem occur yes or no ? This is the question I'm trying to answer proactively.

If I can get the answer to this question proactively, we can imagine a scenario where we make a test in a duplicate database and check if the problem will occur. If the duplicate database tells us that the problem won't occur, then we can make the same change in production no worries. Otherwise, I will have to plan a downtime to make the change.
So my question is more about "Will the problem happen, yes or no ?" before getting to solving it.

DBMS_SESSION.RESET_PACKAGE to reset the package state (as per the linked duplicate - although the other answers to that question also contains many other methods that may solve it).

Thanks @MT0 for your comment. Actually before moving to solving the problem, I'm after a way that tells whether this error may occur or not. Is there any way to detect objects that may be in an inconsistent state ?

If they have state (I.e. non-constant package variables - or, before Oracle 11.2.0.2, constant package variables) then they will be in an inconsistent state after recompilation. The top answer to the linked duplicate mentions what causes the problem.

I need an immediate solution to get the entire objects affected. It's a database with 120 packages. Let's assume I made a change to a column in a table. I need to know immediatly if this is going to cause the problem or not. We are talking about a producation database, analyzing packages one by one to check dependencies may take a huge time. Impossible to do in a production database. Is there any query I can run to get the packages affected ?

If you have changed a column and want to find everything that has been invalidated then https://stackoverflow.com/a/28713519/1509264 (which is a different problem to having invalidated the state of the packages - recompile all the invalid objects to fix the invalid objects problem and then reset the state of the packages to fix the invalid state problem).

Thanks for your comment @MT0. but I think you are missing my point. I have edited the question. Can you please have a look ?

"Now will the problem occur yes or no ?" If your packages have state and they have been recompiled then, yes, they will be in an invalid state. (And if they do not have state then, no, the packages should be in a valid state after recompilation.) As already stated in my last comment (and in the linked duplicate), after recompiling the packages then reset the package state.

@MT0 perfect. Now I understand. Thank you very much !
